# manipulate zeros matrix to put boolean at certain position in rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I have a matrix X of size m,10 that is initialized to all zeros.

then I have a vector of size m,1 that contains digits from 1 to 10

what I want to do (hopefully in a single operation with no loops), is for each row of the matrix X and vector y, I want to put a '1' in the column indexed by the value written in the row of vector y.

Here's what I want with a small example: X = [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]; lets say y=  [3; 2; 1];
then I would expect the operation to return X = [0 0 1; 0 1 0; 1 0 0]

Do you have a command that can do that easily ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X(sub2ind(size(X),y',1:numel(y)))=1
```

or

```
X((0:numel(y)-1)*size(X,2) + y')=1
```